# Orientation in video view

Tags: android, orientation, media, android-videoview

Recently I designed a multimedia player.  But when I try to switch between landscape and portrait modes, the video restarts.

Is there any guide or tutorial for this issue?

I want video to play well in both landscape and portrait view.

This is my sample code in MainActivity.java

```
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);  

            //Creating MediaController  
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);          

          //specify the location of media file  
       Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/video.mp4");

          //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView  
       videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);  
       videoView.setVideoURI(uri);          
       videoView.requestFocus();  
       videoView.start();  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android manifest set this attribute to yor video activity.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: ya i did same thing and it works both for KeyborardHidden and also for screenSize thanks@Sush Now i have one more problem if i want my activity to run in background how an i do this.I mean how to use Service class to do this?

Comment: u cannot run activity in background, service u can run. create a service class and run a looping thread inside it so t will be always running.

Comment: the service class will be created inside MainActivity or it is created as a seprate class i am reading this articlehttp://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: But can you give me a link or resourcethat how to use service in my application?

Comment: depends on ur requirement completely. But i prefere creating it out side.

Comment: u should start the service not link and running a service will make ur app is running not any activity

Comment: so i need not to any tolink my activity this it will automatically run i need to create a seprate class like http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: and inside MainActivity.java i will define it that's it will it work?

Comment: as soon as ur activity get killed serivice will also die. simple. try out side

Comment: public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private static final ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            mMediaPlayer = ... // initialize it here
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
        }
    }

Comment: what should be value of mmediaplayer here and

Comment: 2) mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this); in this line showing error:

Comment: cannot convert from void to mediaplayer